# Linux scheduler preempts low priority thread for too long

Tags: linux, arm, scheduler, thread-priority

I'm developing a multi-process application, which runs on an iMX6 quad core CPU running  linux 3.0.35.
One of the processes/threads I am running require higher priority than the others.

So I use SCHED_FIFO for that thread, and SCHED_OTHER for the others.

While the machine is under heavy load, I noticed that following scenario (using DS5 Streamline profiling tool):

- A low priority thread gets preempted by a high priority thread on CPU
  x.
- While the high priority thread is in CPU x, the other low priority threads get CPU time on other CPUs.  But not the original thread - it doesn't get CPU time for a very long time (even a few seconds)
- When the high-priority thread is done using CPU x, the CPU remains IDLE for a long time (up to 2 seconds) even though there's a heavy load on the machine (10+ threads need the CPU) (the CPU is marked as IDLE in the profiling tool)

I'm looking for ways to understand what that means 
 - Isn't the linux scheduler supposed to give the preempted thread CPU time after it was kicked out of CPU x ?
 - How come the CPU is idle for so long even though there are many threads that require CPU time?

What am I looking at?

I have full access to the kernel code, and some more profiling tools, if it helps.

Thanks,
Ofer

Comment: to confirm that this a general problem, and not something specific to this environment, maybe you can run some tests with different CPU config and different Linux version (maybe something from the 2.x series?) Good luck.

Comment: Migrating processes between CPUs is time consuming.  Moving them is not instantaneous.  The processes have a CPU affinity.  Google [linux smp process affinity](https://www.google.ca/#q=linux+smp++process+affinity).

Comment: Shellter - I'm afraid I don't have the resources to run the test on a different processor. I'll see what I can do regarding a different linux kernel version, although I doubt it is doable for me...

Comment: Artless - using the profiler I noticed some threads switching cores a few times, while this one specific thread remains without CPU time (up to 5 seconds!). So it doesn't feel like a normal behavior to me...

Comment: Have you looked to see that the *one specific thread* isn't waiting on a *mutex*, etc?  Also, how is this thread different?  Is it the main thread?  Did it create the **SCHED_FIFO** thread, etc.

Comment: All low priority threads run a 'while(true){}' loop, while the FIFO priority thread does a sleep(1) once every few seconds.

Comment: Shellter - rerunning on a different development board, with similar kernel, did not reproduce the problem. Any idea what I should look for? I looked for differences in the kernel .config file, and found no diff related to SMP or SCHED....

Comment: I observe a similar issue on a quad-core Intel CPU. Kernel is a 4.1.42. SCHED_OTHER tasks preempted by a SCHED_RR task in a busy loop won't migrate to an idle core. I observed multiple (16) seconds delay.